# Should I use "most important" or "most importantly" in the following case?

Tags: word-choice

Should I use **most important** or **most importantly** in the following:

> *When was the last time I stepped in this house?* she thought. *But **most important/importantly**, what kept me away from it for so long?*

Comment: `Most importantly` modifies `kept` -- that's not what you want according to the context. I guess it should be `But (what is) most important, (is that) what kept me away from it for so long?`

Comment: @Stan I don't understand you construction *is that what ...* - what is your *that* referring to?

Comment: @TrevorD: sorry, I should have written that in two sentences: `But what is most important, is that blah blah` and `..., is what kept me away from it for so long?` I intended to show it may be considered as a predicative clause :)

Comment: @Stan Thanks. I assume you mean that `blah blah and ...` are the reason he stayed away so long. I read the original as a question `Why did I stay away so long?`, `What was it that kept me away so long?`.

Answer (score 2):

Neither; you would say *more importantly*. You have only presented two options in this case, so you must use *more* (thought 2 is *more* important than thought 1). You can only use *most* if 3 or more options are present.

But yes, you use *importantly*, not *important*.

Comment: I'm mainly upvoting because of *importantly*, which is undeniably correct (as should be evident if you just remove the optional comparative/superlative *more/most*). But although I think there's some justification for your "only two options" position, given [74,500](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22of+the+two+the+most%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) instances of *"of the two the most"* in Google Books, I think we have to say it's a long way from being a universally-observed "rule".

Answer (score 0):

You would use "most importantly" or "**more** importantly".
An example of the usage of "most important" is - 'It was most important to stamp the documents.'